# regular expression matching order issue

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code:

```
preg_match(
    '/(,\s?min\s?(?P<min>[\d]+)\s?)?(,\s?max\s?(?P<max>[\d]+)\s?)?/', 
    ',max 1, min 2', 
    $vars
);
```

So, the matching result is:

```
//var_dump($vars):

array (size=7)
  0 => string ',max 1' (length=6)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  'min' => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string '' (length=0)
  3 => string ',max 1' (length=6)
  'max' => string '1' (length=1)
  4 => string '1' (length=1)
```

As can appreciate the value of `min` it is empty `''`.

**I need help to get the value of the data `min` and `max` regardless of the order they appear in the string.**

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Im confused - Can you write out a few examples of sample text as well as what you would like to match? ... I need to see more sample inputs and outputs before I can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grab `min` and `max` irrespective of their order you can use this alternation based regex:

```
\b(?:min\h+\K(?<min>\d+)|max\h+\K(?<max>\d+))\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tG2sS1/1)

Use captured group names `min` and `max` to extract the value from resulting array after `preg_match_all` function call.

Comment: there any way to do this using preg_match only? thanks.

Comment: using `preg_match_all` the result is multidimentional and the value of `min` and `max` into array will vary depending on their position in the string. I explain?

Comment: if not posible using `preg_match` only, anyway thanks.

Comment: I do not understand @anubhava, I see `min => ''` in you demo.

Comment: My mistake, yes you would need `preg_match_all` to get both values

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?J)(?:,\s?min\s?(?P<min>\d+)\s?)(?:,\s?max\s?(?P<max>\d+)\s?)?|(?:,\s?max\s?(?P<max>\d+)\s?)(?:,\s?min\s?(?P<min>\d+)\s?)?
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sT6wE6/1)

The regex is basically yours, I just added a `(?J)` modifier that allows reusing capture names in the same regex, and added an alternative with another order of `min` and `max`. Also, I removed square brackets from around `\d`.

[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/9N4Nlo):

```
$re = '/(?J)(?:,\s?min\s?(?P<min>\d+)\s?)(?:,\s?max\s?(?P<max>\d+)\s?)?|(?:,\s?max\s?(?P<max>\d+)\s?)(?:,\s?min\s?(?P<min>\d+)\s?)?/'; 
if (preg_match($re, ",max 1, min 2", $matches)){
    print_r($matches["max"] . " = max and min = " . $matches["min"] . PHP_EOL);
}
if (preg_match($re, ",min 5, max 6", $matches)){
    print_r($matches["max"] . " = max and min = " . $matches["min"] . PHP_EOL);
}
if (preg_match($re, ", min 7", $matches)){
    print_r($matches["max"] . " = max and min = " . $matches["min"] . PHP_EOL);
}
if (preg_match($re, ",max 8", $matches)){
    print_r($matches["max"] . " = max and min = " . $matches["min"]);
}
```

Results:

```
1 = max and min = 2
6 = max and min = 5
 = max and min = 7
8 = max and min =
```